# Android Listview with Search filter

Tags: android

I am trying to make a listView search for Android.I am using SimpleCursorAdapter on onTextChanged
i have found a error adapter cannot be resolved or is not a field.how can resolve this error .I am using SimpleCursorAdapter .I am not able to use adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

```
ListView lv;
Cursor cursur1;
EditText search ;
int textlength=0;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
     search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    final String [] from={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
    int [] m={android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

    lv=getListView();
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    cursur1=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursur1);


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

     SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursur1, from,m);
     setListAdapter(adapter);


    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilters().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }); 

}

@Override
public long getSelectedItemId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getSelectedItemId();
}

@Override
public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. inside add Text change listener

```
YourAdapterOrWhateverAdapter adapter = (YourAdapterOrWhateverAdapter) listView.getAdapter();  
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use AutoCompleteTextView, e.g -

```
    private static final String[] DATE_RANGE = new String[] { "1 Day",
        "2 Days", "3 Days", "6 Months", "1 Year", "Blank" };

    AutoCompleteTextView dateRangeTV = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_date_range);
    dateRangeTV.setThreshold(0);

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.default_date_range_list, DATE_RANGE);
   dateRangeTV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In Touch event, you could see the dropdownlist :

```
  dateRangeTV.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                dateRangeTV.showDropDown();

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Type any text, It'll show your matching text from the list.

For more see the tutorial of the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm)